# Tkinter - Subprocess to create user

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

I have written the following to allow users to be added,the script runs fine with no errros but no user account is created.

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess


def add():
        subprocess.call(['adduser', '-N', '-g', group.get(), '-c',  fname.get(), '-d', '/home/oucu.get()'])


root = Tk()
oucu = StringVar()
e2 = Entry(root, textvariable=oucu).grid(row=0, column=1)
fname = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(root, textvariable=fname).grid(row=1, column=1)
sname = StringVar()
e4 = Entry(root, textvariable=sname).grid(row=2, column=1)
group = StringVar()
e6 = Entry(root, textvariable=group).grid(row=3, column=1)
b1 = Button(root, text='Next', command=add).grid(row=4, column=1)

Label(root, text="Users Oucu").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="First Name").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="Last Name").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="Group").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `grid()` returns nothing, so all your widget variables using it are `None`.

Comment: which line are you referring to Martin?

Comment: Your question doesn't ask anything. What do you need help with?

Comment: Geo: Lines like `e6 = Entry(root, textvariable=group).grid(row=3, column=1)`. After execution, `e6` will be set to `None`. Regardless, I suggest you add a `print(group.get(), fname.get())` to the beginning of the `add()` function and make sure the values are correct.

Comment: @Bryan: I think the "the script runs fine with no errros but no user account is created" is fairly clear.

Comment: Correct basically it should add a user to the system according to the subprocess by getting the  Group, Fname and Oucu entry from the input.

Comment: @martineau  thank you but I am still confused on what you mean, could you edit 1 line to help me understand if possible, please?

Comment: Geo: I don't think this is necessarily the cause of your problem, but you need to understand it if you're going to use Tkinter. To avoid the (potential) problem, the line I mentioned in an earlier comment would need to be split into two statements: `e6 = Entry(root, textvariable=group)`, followed by `e6.grid(row=3, column=1)` that way, `e6` will refer to the `Entry` widget and not be set to `None` which doesn't refer to anything (obviously).

Comment: Are you running the python script from an account that has privilege to add users? If not, the subprocess is probably quietly failing. The OS will run subprocesses with the same privileges as the python process user.

Comment: @martineau: the reason I asked is because  the question could be about the proper command line arguments to "adduser", or it could be how to get the stdout and/or stderr of a call to `subprocess.call`, or it could be about something else. Just saying "It's not working" is generally considered off topic.

Comment: @Ron Norris The account has privileges yes was the first thing I checked, if anyone has an environment to give it a quick test it would great!

Comment: @Bryan You have a solid point and the question is more likely falling to both points. Even though i don't have much experience i did spent quite a long time researching the subprocess module and the commands.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself exactly what `'/home/oucu.get()'` is doing. I doubt it's doing what you think it's doing.